# I'm having an error with Char.chr

Tags: char, ocaml

I made my own uppercase but while testing it I'm getting the same error all time with Char.chr **Invalid_argument "Char.chr"**

*This is the test i'm using for:*

```
let rec letra n =
    let c = Char.chr n in 
        if n=256 then -1
        else if uppercase c = Char.uppercase c then letra (n+1)
            else n;;
```

Do you have any idea why is giving me this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `Char.chr` doesn't accept values over 255.

Your test `if n=256` should be done before calling Char.chr.

Note that `Char.uppercase` has been deprecated since 4.03 because it is designed for ISO Latin-1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I owe you one.